# MySQL get percentage from day

Tags: mysql, algorithm

I have a query which looks like this

```
select *
 from (

      select 
        user_id,
        created_at,
        event_name,
        count(*) as num_of_events,
        (count(*)/SUM(count(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY created_at))*100 AS pct_of_daily_total
      from events
      where event_name = 'post_submit' or event_name = 'post_cancel'
      group by event_name, created_at ) sub
```

This yields a result that looks like this

```
user_id, created_at,    event_name,    num_of_event,    pct_of_daily_total
123      2019-01-01     post_submit    1                100.000
456      2019-01-02     post_cancel    1                25.000
456      2019-01-02     post_submit    3                75.000
456      2019-01-03     post_cancel    1                100.000
```

I am looking to have a final output which shows the success rate of each day regardless of user id. Each event type of post submit is a success, and post cancel is unsuccessful. The final result should be

```
dt             success_rate%
2019-01-01     100
2019-01-02     75
2019-01-03     0
```

Comment: Since you don't have `user_id` in the grouping, your result is already regardless of user id. The user_id in the result is just a random choice from the group. If you enable `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` you'd get an error from this query.

Comment: If you want the success rate by day, take `event_name` out of `group by`.